# Help with C# HttpWebRequest URI losing its encoding

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, asp.net-3.5, url-encoding

Having a problem with HttpWebRequest decoding my encoded URL.

```
var requestUrl = "https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/feeds/http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2example%2Ecom%2F/crawlissues/";   
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
```

When looking at end request URL is becomes:

**https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/feeds/http://www.example.com//crawlissues/**

Which of course returns a 400 Bad request. I am guessing it is something todo with the URI class rather than HttpWebRequest. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: What is the output URL that you are expecting ? Thanks

Comment: The URL is meant to be https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/feeds/http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2example%2Ecom%2F/crawlissues/ as you can see the domain is encoded and needs to stay encoded.

Answer (score 5):

This is an annoying "security feature" of the Uri class. If you're using 4.0 or later, you can [turn it off in your configuration file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656542%28v=vs.100%29.aspx); otherwise, you'll have to [resort to reflection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xiangfan/archive/2012/01/16/10256915.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Richard! I've been looking everywhere for this--the following works like a charm in .net 4.5
   <uri>
    <schemeSettings>
      <add name = "http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
    </schemeSettings>
  </uri>

Comment: Config file can also disable it on 4.6.

Comment: @r590: Correct. I should have said "4.0 or later", but that meant "4.0 or 4.5" when I posted this. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can request that url.

It won't decode `%2F` in a query parameter. So, it would work if the encoded data was in a query parameter:

```
requestUrl = "https://google.com/tools?feeds=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2example%2Ecom%2F/crawlissues/";   
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way to this

```
var request=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Uri.EscapeUriString(requestUrl));
request.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding","binary");
```

worked like a charm for me

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but may be [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) method will help.

**Upd.** Alternatively you may use WebClient class.

Comment: Thanks but the url is already encoded, the problem is that something is decoding it.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Oddly a URL that is not decoded when I run under IISExpress in Visual Studios debugging the site, IS decoded when running under IIS proper. The decoding breaks the URL!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Request method from POST to GET